# CSS layering z-index issues

Tags: css, sass

Hoping a 2nd set of eyes will help. I have the same code used on two different modules, yet the newest one isn't doing what I need.

I have a module with 50/50 content internal contents. The one side has an image + title. The image should be under the title. I did this with z-index on a different module, yet, this one isn't working, the image disappears

```css
#wrapper {width: 100%;}
.mod-sub-links {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mod-sub-links-img,
.mod-sub-links-copy {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.mod-sub-links-img {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mod-sub-links-img img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.mod-sub-links-img h2 {
  color: #fefefe;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
.mod-sub-links-copy {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fefefe;
  background: #3d61a4;
}
.mod-sub-links-copy a > i.fa {
  color: #3d61a4;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 8px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="mod-sub-links clearfix">
  <div class="mod-sub-links-img float-left">
    <h2>Engineering</h2>
    <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-sub-links-copy float-left">
    <h4>Main Precision Statement</h4>
    <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Main Precision Statement</p>
    <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>
    <h4>Main Precision Statement</h4>
    <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Main Precision Statement</p>
    <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

WORKING CODE

```js
!function(i,t){var n,e="superslides";n=function(n,e){this.options=t.extend({play:!1,animation_speed:600,animation_easing:"swing",animation:"slide",inherit_width_from:i,inherit_height_from:i,pagination:!0,hashchange:!1,scrollable:!0,elements:{preserve:".preserve",nav:".slides-navigation",container:".slides-container",pagination:".slides-pagination"}},e);var s=this,o=t("<div>",{class:"slides-control"}),a=1;this.$el=t(n),this.$container=this.$el.find(this.options.elements.container);var r=function(){return a=s._findMultiplier(),s.$el.on("click",s.options.elements.nav+" a",function(i){i.preventDefault(),s.stop(),t(this).hasClass("next")?s.animate("next",function(){s.start()}):s.animate("prev",function(){s.start()})}),t(document).on("keyup",function(i){37===i.keyCode&&s.animate("prev"),39===i.keyCode&&s.animate("next")}),t(i).on("resize",function(){setTimeout(function(){var i=s.$container.children();s.width=s._findWidth(),s.height=s._findHeight(),i.css({width:s.width,left:s.width}),s.css.containers(),s.css.images()},10)}),t(i).on("hashchange",function(){var i,t=s._parseHash();i=t&&!isNaN(t)?s._upcomingSlide(t-1):s._upcomingSlide(t),i>=0&&i!==s.current&&s.animate(i)}),s.pagination._events(),s.start(),s},c={containers:function(){s.init?(s.$el.css({height:s.height}),s.$control.css({width:s.width*a,left:-s.width}),s.$container.css({})):(t("body").css({margin:0}),s.$el.css({position:"relative",overflow:"hidden",width:"100%",height:s.height}),s.$control.css({position:"relative",transform:"translate3d(0)",height:"100%",width:s.width*a,left:-s.width}),s.$container.css({display:"none",margin:"0",padding:"0",listStyle:"none",position:"relative",height:"100%"})),1===s.size()&&s.$el.find(s.options.elements.nav).hide()},images:function(){var i=s.$container.find("img").not(s.options.elements.preserve);i.removeAttr("width").removeAttr("height").css({"-webkit-backface-visibility":"hidden","-ms-interpolation-mode":"bicubic",position:"absolute",left:"0",top:"0","z-index":"-1","max-width":"none"}),i.each(function(){var i=s.image._aspectRatio(this),n=this;if(t.data(this,"processed"))s.image._scale(n,i),s.image._center(n,i);else{var e=new Image;e.onload=function(){s.image._scale(n,i),s.image._center(n,i),t.data(n,"processed",!0)},e.src=this.src}})},children:function(){var i=s.$container.children();i.is("img")&&(i.each(function(){if(t(this).is("img")){t(this).wrap("<div>");var i=t(this).attr("id");t(this).removeAttr("id"),t(this).parent().attr("id",i)}}),i=s.$container.children()),s.init||i.css({display:"none",left:2*s.width}),i.css({position:"absolute",overflow:"hidden",height:"100%",width:s.width,top:0,zIndex:0})}},h={slide:function(i,t){var n=s.$container.children(),e=n.eq(i.upcoming_slide);e.css({left:i.upcoming_position,display:"block"}),s.$control.animate({left:i.offset},s.options.animation_speed,s.options.animation_easing,function(){s.size()>1&&(s.$control.css({left:-s.width}),n.eq(i.upcoming_slide).css({left:s.width,zIndex:2}),i.outgoing_slide>=0&&n.eq(i.outgoing_slide).css({left:s.width,display:"none",zIndex:0})),t()})},fade:function(i,t){var n=this,e=n.$container.children(),s=e.eq(i.outgoing_slide),o=e.eq(i.upcoming_slide);o.css({left:this.width,opacity:1,display:"block"}),i.outgoing_slide>=0?s.animate({opacity:0},n.options.animation_speed,n.options.animation_easing,function(){n.size()>1&&(e.eq(i.upcoming_slide).css({zIndex:2}),i.outgoing_slide>=0&&e.eq(i.outgoing_slide).css({opacity:1,display:"none",zIndex:0})),t()}):(o.css({zIndex:2}),t())}};h=t.extend(h,t.fn.superslides.fx);var d={_centerY:function(i){var n=t(i);n.css({top:(s.height-n.height())/2})},_centerX:function(i){var n=t(i);n.css({left:(s.width-n.width())/2})},_center:function(i){s.image._centerX(i),s.image._centerY(i)},_aspectRatio:function(i){if(!i.naturalHeight&&!i.naturalWidth){var t=new Image;t.src=i.src,i.naturalHeight=t.height,i.naturalWidth=t.width}return i.naturalHeight/i.naturalWidth},_scale:function(i,n){n=n||s.image._aspectRatio(i);var e=s.height/s.width,o=t(i);e>n?o.css({height:s.height,width:s.height/n}):o.css({height:s.width*n,width:s.width})}},l={_setCurrent:function(i){if(s.$pagination){var t=s.$pagination.children();t.removeClass("current"),t.eq(i).addClass("current")}},_addItem:function(i){var n=i+1,e=n,o=s.$container.children().eq(i),a=o.attr("id");a&&(e=a);var r=t("<a>",{href:"#"+e,text:e});r.appendTo(s.$pagination)},_setup:function(){if(s.options.pagination&&1!==s.size()){var i=t("<nav>",{class:s.options.elements.pagination.replace(/^\./,"")});s.$pagination=i.appendTo(s.$el);for(var n=0;s.size()>n;n++)s.pagination._addItem(n)}},_events:function(){s.$el.on("click",s.options.elements.pagination+" a",function(i){i.preventDefault();var t=s._parseHash(this.hash),n=s._upcomingSlide(t-1);n!==s.current&&s.animate(n,function(){s.start()})})}};return this.css=c,this.image=d,this.pagination=l,this.fx=h,this.animation=this.fx[this.options.animation],this.$control=this.$container.wrap(o).parent(".slides-control"),s._findPositions(),s.width=s._findWidth(),s.height=s._findHeight(),this.css.children(),this.css.containers(),this.css.images(),this.pagination._setup(),r()},n.prototype={_findWidth:function(){return t(this.options.inherit_width_from).width()},_findHeight:function(){return t(this.options.inherit_height_from).height()},_findMultiplier:function(){return 1===this.size()?1:3},_upcomingSlide:function(i){if(/next/.test(i))return this._nextInDom();if(/prev/.test(i))return this._prevInDom();if(/\d/.test(i))return+i;if(i&&/\w/.test(i)){var t=this._findSlideById(i);return t>=0?t:0}return 0},_findSlideById:function(i){return this.$container.find("#"+i).index()},_findPositions:function(i,t){t=t||this,void 0===i&&(i=-1),t.current=i,t.next=t._nextInDom(),t.prev=t._prevInDom()},_nextInDom:function(){var i=this.current+1;return i===this.size()&&(i=0),i},_prevInDom:function(){var i=this.current-1;return 0>i&&(i=this.size()-1),i},_parseHash:function(t){return t=t||i.location.hash,t=t.replace(/^#/,""),t&&!isNaN(+t)&&(t=+t),t},size:function(){return this.$container.children().length},destroy:function(){return this.$el.removeData()},update:function(){this.css.children(),this.css.containers(),this.css.images(),this.pagination._addItem(this.size()),this._findPositions(this.current),this.$el.trigger("updated.slides")},stop:function(){clearInterval(this.play_id),delete this.play_id,this.$el.trigger("stopped.slides")},start:function(){var n=this;n.options.hashchange?t(i).trigger("hashchange"):this.animate(),this.options.play&&(this.play_id&&this.stop(),this.play_id=setInterval(function(){n.animate()},this.options.play)),this.$el.trigger("started.slides")},animate:function(t,n){var e=this,s={};if(!(this.animating||(this.animating=!0,void 0===t&&(t="next"),s.upcoming_slide=this._upcomingSlide(t),s.upcoming_slide>=this.size()))){if(s.outgoing_slide=this.current,s.upcoming_position=2*this.width,s.offset=-s.upcoming_position,("prev"===t||s.outgoing_slide>t)&&(s.upcoming_position=0,s.offset=0),e.size()>1&&e.pagination._setCurrent(s.upcoming_slide),e.options.hashchange){var o=s.upcoming_slide+1,a=e.$container.children(":eq("+s.upcoming_slide+")").attr("id");i.location.hash=a?a:o}e.$el.trigger("animating.slides",[s]),e.animation(s,function(){e._findPositions(s.upcoming_slide,e),"function"==typeof n&&n(),e.animating=!1,e.$el.trigger("animated.slides"),e.init||(e.$el.trigger("init.slides"),e.init=!0,e.$container.fadeIn("fast"))})}}},t.fn[e]=function(i,s){var o=[];return this.each(function(){var a,r,c;return a=t(this),r=a.data(e),c="object"==typeof i&&i,r||(o=a.data(e,r=new n(this,c))),"string"==typeof i&&(o=r[i],"function"==typeof o)?o=o.call(r,s):void 0}),o},t.fn[e].fx={}}(this,jQuery),$(document).foundation(),$(function(){"use strict";$.hamburger=$("#nav-toggle"),$.nav=$(".primary-nav"),$.hamburger.click(function(i){$(this).toggleClass("active"),i.preventDefault(),$.nav.slideToggle(500)}),$("#slides").superslides({play:5e3,animation:"fade",pagination:!1}),$("#slides-int").superslides(),$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(){if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")===this.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")&&location.hostname===this.hostname){var i=$(this.hash);if(i=i.length?i:$("[name="+this.hash.slice(1)+"]"),i.length)return $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:i.offset().top},1e3),!1}}),$(".mod-accordion-bottom").click(function(){var i=$(this).closest(".mod-accordion-wrap").toggleClass("active"),t=i.hasClass("active");if(i.find(".mod-accordion-bottom i").toggleClass("fa-minus",t).toggleClass("fa-plus",!t),i.find(".mod-accordion-content")[t?"slideDown":"slideUp"]("normal"),t){var n=$(".mod-accordion-wrap.active").not(i).removeClass("active");n.find(".mod-accordion-content").slideUp(),n.find(".mod-accordion-bottom i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus")}}),$(".toggle-wrap").click(function(){$(".toggle-content").toggleClass("open"),$(this).find(".filters").slideToggle(100)})});
```

```css
.mod-accordion-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem; }
  .mod-accordion-wrap.active .mod-accordion-top {
    background-color: #3d61a4; }
    .mod-accordion-wrap.active .mod-accordion-top-title-icon i.fa {
      color: #ffee00; }

.mod-accordion-top {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  background: #282c2f; }
  .mod-accordion-top-title, .mod-accordion-top-image {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    max-height: 10.3125rem; }
  .mod-accordion-top-image {
    position: relative; }
    .mod-accordion-top-image img {
      margin-top: -7%; }
    .mod-accordion-top-image.investors img {
      margin-top: -40%; }
  .mod-accordion-top-title {
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    .mod-accordion-top-title-copy, .mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
      width: 100%;
      float: left; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
        .mod-accordion-top-title-copy, .mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
          width: 48%; } }
    .mod-accordion-top-title-copy {
      margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
      padding: 0 155px 0 0; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
        .mod-accordion-top-title-copy {
          border-right: 2px solid #fefefe;
          min-height: 113px; } }
    .mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
      text-align: center; }
      .mod-accordion-top-title-icon i.fa {
        margin-top: 50px; }
        .mod-accordion-top-title-icon i.fa.active {
          color: #ffee00; }

.mod-accordion-content {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0.625rem 0; }
  .mod-accordion-content-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0.625rem; }
    .mod-accordion-content-wrap:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0; }
  .mod-accordion-content-title, .mod-accordion-content-copy {
    width: 100%; }
    @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
      .mod-accordion-content-title, .mod-accordion-content-copy {
        width: 50%;
        float: left; } }
  .mod-accordion-content-copy {
    padding: 25px 35px 25px 25px;
    background-color: #3d61a4;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 21.875rem; }
    .mod-accordion-content-copy h4, .mod-accordion-content-copy p {
      text-align: left; }
    .mod-accordion-content-copy a {
      color: #3d61a4;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      padding: 3px 0 0;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 40px auto 0;
      display: block;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }
      .mod-accordion-content-copy a:hover {
        background-color: #faa74a;
        color: #fefefe; }
  .mod-accordion-content-title {
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    .mod-accordion-content-title h2 {
      padding: 20px; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
        .mod-accordion-content-title h2 {
          margin: 20px;
          padding: 0; } }
    .mod-accordion-content-title img {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: -1; }

.mod-accordion-bottom {
  background-color: #b4b6b7;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center; }
  .mod-accordion-bottom.active, .mod-accordion-bottom:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #3d61a4; }
  .mod-accordion-bottom i.fa {
    color: #3d61a4;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    padding: 8px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer; }
    .mod-accordion-bottom i.fa.fa-minus {
      color: #faa74a; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d7ed46e5fb.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="mod-accordion-wrap">
            <div class="mod-accordion-top">
              <div class="mod-accordion-top-title">
                <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-copy">
                  <h4>Our Story</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-icon show-for-medium">
                  <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mod-accordion-top-image">
                <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
              </div>
            </div><!-- END Top -->
            <div class="mod-accordion-content">
              <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
                  <h2>Precision</h2>
                  <img src="images/HS6C4209.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
                  <h4>Main Precision Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <h4>Second Precision Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
                  <h2>Engineering</h2>
                  <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
                  <h4>Main Engineering Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <h4>Second Engineering Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: `z-index: -1;` moves an element *behind* its container. So if the container does not have an at least slightly transparent background it "vanishes".

Comment: But there is no background on the container for the image (or the wrapper for the whole thing). That's what's confusing me. It's working in another module without issue. Nearly identical code.

Comment: Even running the code HERE, it looks to be working ... maybe I'm spinning my wheels on this one...

Comment: Show us the code that does work and we'll see if we can spot it for you.

Comment: @LGSon -- added working code I modified this from on another page.

Answer (score 0):

I simply made the H2s pos:abs so they stay on top of the image.